# JQuery validation code will not allow deletion of entered text

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I borrowed a bit of code from this question (see reply 4):

[how do i block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)

However, upon using the code, it appears, that although it does the validation as you type neatly, it does not allow you to edit anything you have entered.

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function (event) {
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
if (!regex.test(key)) {
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;
}});
```

I am a bit confused, I have tried to adjust it by changing the keypress to keyup but this just stops the validation from working. Any pointers would be graciously accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a browser specific issue. In Firefox keypress includes meta keys like backspace and the arrow keys while Chrome does not. If you adjust your logic a bit to prefer which over charCode (which I think is better supported anyways) you end up with this

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function(event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var code = event.charCode === 0 ? event.which : event.charCode;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(code);
    if (!regex.test(key) && code !== 8) {
         // 8 is ascii code for backspace
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
    }
});
```

This fiddle also writes to console the keys and codes being passed in the event when typing.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q2MWS/5/

Comment: Thank you JaredMcAteer, that works just lovely - greatly appreciated. Although I now have to figure out how to handle pasted input.

Comment: @BernieDavies There is an `onpaste` event you can hook into and validate the text pasted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601353/detect-paste-on-input-box

Answer (score 0):

I think event.preventDefault() is preventing editing of entered chars if they are not matching the regexp. Check event.which/event.charCode for other values like backspace, space, decimal-point-key etc

Comment: Hmm, just read the event.which stuff on jquery docs and it is a bit confusing. I think I might revert to a more standard approach unless anyone has any other suggestions. Thank you for the reply though. Appreciated.