# JQuery: detect change in input field

Tags: jquery, keypress

I want to detect when a user's keyboard actions alter the value of a text field. It should work consistently across modern browsers.

The JQuery page for the .keypress event says it's not consistent? Also, it doesn't work for backspace, delete etc.

I can't use .keydown as it is because it reacts to shift, alt and arrow keys etc. Also, it doesn't fire more than once when the user holds down a key and multiple characters are inserted.

Is there a concise method I'm missing? Or should I use .keydown and filter out events that are triggered by arrow keys, shift and so on? My main concern is there will be keys that I'm not aware should be filtered. (I nearly forgot about alt and ctrl, I suppose there could be others) But then how would I detect the key being held down and inserting multiple characters?

As a bonus it would detect changes due to pasting (including right-clicking) but I have the solution to that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601353/detect-paste-on-input-box).

Answer (score 862, accepted):

You can bind the 'input' event to the textbox. This would fire **every time** the input changes, so when you paste something (even with right click), delete and type anything.

```
$('#myTextbox').on('input', function() {
    // do something
});
```

If you use the `change` handler, this will only fire after the user deselects the input box, which may not be what you want.

There is an example of both here: http://jsfiddle.net/6bSX6/

Comment: This does not work in the Nintendo 3DS browser. The change is not detected even though the input field contains the new string.

Comment: @Gatada I'm glad my employer does not make me verify web code for the Nintendo 3DS browser.

Comment: this will fail for input fields that are generated AFTER initial page load, like the popular *select2* plugin

Comment: @Sliq Can be fixed by changing it to `$(document).on("input", "#myTextbox", function() {...})`. This will trigger for all runtime-generated inputs with this ID.

Comment: @Timm, will this work, if I set value of input #myTextbox via Jquery, like `$('#myTexbox').val('some_value') ? Thanks

Answer (score 26):

Use jquery [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event,
>   or trigger that event on an element.

An example

```
$("input[type='text']").change( function() {
  // your code
});
```

The advantage that `.change` has over `.keypress` , `.focus` , `.blur` is that `.change` event will fire only *when input has changed*

Comment: does it work with select dropdowns?

Answer (score 12):

Same functionality i recently achieved using below function.

I wanted to enable SAVE button on edit.

1. Change event is NOT advisable as it will ONLY be fired if after editing, mouse is clicked somewhere else on the page before clicking SAVE button.
2. Key Press doesnt handle Backspace, Delete and Paste options.
3. Key Up handles everything including tab, Shift key.

Hence i wrote below function combining keypress, keyup (for backspace, delete) and paste event for text fields.

Hope it helps you.

```
function checkAnyFormFieldEdited() {
    /*
     * If any field is edited,then only it will enable Save button
     */
    $(':text').keypress(function(e) { // text written
        enableSaveBtn();
    });

    $(':text').keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) { //backspace and delete key
            enableSaveBtn();
        } else { // rest ignore
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $(':text').bind('paste', function(e) { // text pasted
        enableSaveBtn();
    });

    $('select').change(function(e) { // select element changed
        enableSaveBtn();
    });

    $(':radio').change(function(e) { // radio changed
        enableSaveBtn();
    });

    $(':password').keypress(function(e) { // password written
        enableSaveBtn();
    });
    $(':password').bind('paste', function(e) { // password pasted
        enableSaveBtn();
    });


}
```

Comment: Indeed, `keyup` seemed to be the only one (not `keypress` or `keydown`) that would detect backspace and delete operations, at least in IE 8 and IE 9. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Use `$.on()` to bind your chosen event to the input, don't use the shortcuts like `$.keydown()` etc because as of jQuery 1.7 `$.on()` is the preferred method to attach event handlers (see here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ and http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

`$.keydown()` is just a shortcut to `$.bind('keydown')`, and `$.bind()` is what `$.on()` replaces (among others).

To answer your question, as far as I'm aware, unless you need to fire an event on `keydown` specifically, the `change` event should do the trick for you.

```
$('element').on('change', function(){
    console.log('change');
});
```

To respond to the below comment, the javascript `change` event is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

And here is a working example of the `change` event working on an input element, using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/p1m4xh08/

Comment: No 'change' event on input elements

Comment: @Daniel you are mistaken - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange

Comment: sorry, second link wrong - see this one for more info: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#event-input-change

Comment: So read again the link and you'll see: "Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value." Which seems what the person posting the question needs

Comment: @Daniel you said that there was no change event, not that it didn't fire every time. That was incorrect, there *is* a change event. I've read the docs too. Obviously, the selected answer, which advises using the `input` event, fits the needs of the OP. The selected answer also makes mention of the `change` event and why it might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: You are correct!, my 'no event existence' statement is not correct ;).

Comment: @Daniel & totallyNotLizards that is not how I read it... Sounded like Daniel was saying "don't use change" on inputs for this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery change() function

```
$('input').change(function(){
  //your codes
});
```

There are examples on how to use it on the API Page: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Note for textfields this only is detected onblur