# Ignore focus on jquery.change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example I have the following code:

```
    $(".someSelector").change(function()
    {
        // Do something

        // Call function

        // console.log('test')

    });
```

The problem is, it is being called twice: whenever I lose focus of the input field and whenever the value changes.

I want it to be called only whenever the value changes.

Is there a way to ignore focus loss on the .change other than comparing old input value with the new input value?

Comment: it will already be called only when the value changed in your case

Comment: Something is wrong with your question: `onchange` event does not fire if value is not changed. It fired on blur only if the value has changed after focus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead of `change`.

`input` is fired on each value change (including paste); `change`fires on blur when the value has changed.

```
$(".someSelector").on('input', function() {
    // Do something
});
```

The `input` event is [supported by IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer from another question which I think applies to you as well:

You can bind the 'input' event to the textbox. This would fire every time the input changes, so when you paste something (even with right click), delete and type anything.

```
$('#myTextbox').on('input', function() {
    // do something
});
```

If you use the change handler, this will only fire after the user deselects the input box, which may not be what you want.

Source: [JQuery: detect change in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797700/jquery-detect-change-in-input-field)