# Change payment gateway when textarea is filled

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In Woocommerce I have created a custom text area field in the checkout page

so if I write anything on the textarea the payment gateway will change to "Cheque" and if there is nothing then it will be only "paypal"

I have no idea how to do this as I have very little knowledge in WooCommerce

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_product', array(

   'type' => 'textarea',
   'label'      => __('Custom products', 'woocommerce'),
   'required'   => false,
   'class'      => array('form-row-wide'),
   'clear'     => true,
       ), $checkout->get_value( 'custom_product' ));
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is it just a checkbox that needs to be clicked to change payment gateway?

Comment: Hi @SergioAlen it is not a checkbox, it should be a textarea. so when I start writing in the textarea the payment gateway changes as well

Comment: yes but, is there a way already to change payment gateway without the text area?

Comment: none as of the moment, I dont know what to do... :-(

Comment: In the admin area go to Dashboard > WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout. Select the payment methods you'd like to accept in this case PayPal and Cheque, once you do that you should see in the checkout 2 checkboxes to select the payment method http://wpbeaches.com/woocommerce-payment-gateway-order/ let me know when done

Comment: Hi, done with that @SergioAlen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135023/discussion-between-sergio-alen-and-francis-alvin-tan).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that with some simple jQuery script depending on which payment gateway you want to enable.

> May be you need first **to add an additional CSS class** to your **`texarea`**, to better target it with the query script *(I have completed a little bit your code for testing purpose only)*.

So your complete code function will be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_textarea_field', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_textarea_field( $checkout ){

    echo '<div id="custom-texarea-field">
        <h2>' . __('My Field Title', 'woocommerce') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'custom_product', array(

       'type' => 'textarea',
       'label'      => __('Custom products', 'woocommerce'),
       'required'   => false,
       'class'      => array('custom-product-ta form-row-wide'), ## @ <== HERE
       'clear'     => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'custom_product' ));

    echo '</div>';

}
```

Then now you can add also the code below hooked in **`woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details`** checkout action hook, that will embed some query script into your checkout page.

> The jQuery script is going to enabled, in this example, the radio button for Cheque payment method, when your text area will be filled with something.

So this is the additional code for that purpose:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details','custom_jquery_for_texarea');
function custom_jquery_for_texarea(){
   ?>
   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('.custom-product-ta textarea').on('input', function(){
            $('.wc_payment_method payment_method_cheque > input[name=payment_method]').prop('checked', true); 
       });
   });
   </script>
   <?php 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

**This code is tested and works…**

---

Related answer to jQuery code: [JQuery: detect change in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797700/jquery-detect-change-in-input-field/12797900#12797900)

WooCommerce documentation: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the checkboxes to select payment methods on the checkout page then you can use jQuery to simulate a click once the text area is filled:

```
jQuery('textarea').on('input', function(){
  jQuery('#payment_method_cheque').click(); // check if the radio input has this id #payment_method_cheque and change if not
});
```