# Alter the href of an anchor tag with form values and follow the new link with a single click

Tags: javascript, html, href

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365246/how-to-change-href-of-a-tag-on-button-click-through-javascript) ( Arindam Roychowdhury ) shows how a text box value can be used to change the href of an anchor tag.

```
<html>
<body>

Hi everyone

<p id="result"></p>

<textarea cols="40" id="SearchText" rows="2"></textarea>

<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Submit!</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var result = document.getElementById("SearchText").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
        document.getElementById("abc").href="http://arindam31.pythonanywhere.com/hello/" + result;
}       
</script>


<a href="#" id="abc">abc</a>
```

Brilliant! But in order to navigate to the new url, you need to click the anchor tag. *Two clicks* to do the job.

Is it possible to click the anchor and run JS code which changes the href and then navigates to the new url? Just a *single click* to get to the new url. Thanks.

This is the revised code implementing the window.location code phuzi proposed...

```
<p id="result"></p>
<textarea cols="40" id="SearchText" rows="2"></textarea>

<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Submit!</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var result = document.getElementById("SearchText").value;
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;

   window.location= "http://example.com/live/" + result;
}       
</script>
```

**Another thought:**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797700/jquery-detect-change-in-input-field) shows the use of on.input to monitor a text box for every change. If code is included to update the href of an anchor tag and when the user moves to the link with the updated href, clicking it will pass the current value in all the fields.

```
<style>

p.hidden {
  display: none;
}

</style>

<p id="result" class="hidden">  </p>

<textarea cols="40" id="SearchText" rows="1"></textarea>

<script>

jQuery('#SearchText').on('input', function() {
    //alert('Text1 changed!');
     var result = document.getElementById("SearchText").value;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
        document.getElementById("abc").href="http://example.com/live/" + 
        result;
});

</script>


<a href="#" class="colorbox-popup" id="abc">Add New Record</a>
```

Using an href has an advantage over a simple re-direct by allowing a class to be attached - in this case to open the new link in a pop-up.

Thanks again to everyone for their help on this.

Comment: `Window.location = 'Your new url'` no need to update the href on the anchor tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript)

Comment: Try this. https://jsfiddle.net/pbu1f3Ly/ It is just applied what @phuzi suggested.

Comment: Thanks phuzi. As you say, no need for updating the anchor tag. What is good is that this works inside a Drupal page without giving any errors. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you would want to do this, but you can easily set the `href` property and then navigate to whatever that URL is by doing something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.target.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
});
```

```html
<a id="link" href="#" /> Click Me </a>
```

If you wanted to do with a button, same thing(ish):

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const anchor = document.getElementById('link');
  anchor.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
  window.location = anchor.href;
});
```

```html
<a id="link" href="#" /> This is an anchor tag </a>

<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works fine outside Drupal but in a Drupal page I get... Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at j5:286.  If I find a solution from a Drupal expert here, I'll post again.

Comment: That is because it's not picking up the element. Are you sure the selector is correct and the element exists?